# How to include css and js files in Node.js project

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

What is the correct way to include css and js files in express project ?

I am using ejs template engine. I have seen one example using connect-assetmanager but it was difficult to follow.

A small example project which includes css and js in index.ejs (not layout.ejs) would be very useful.

Comment: Are you also compiling the JS and CSS, or are you just looking to serve static JS and CSS files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Static files can be served with express' static middleware. I usually make a directory for all static files to be served from the root.

If you've installed express globally with npm (`npm install -g express`) you can type the following at the command line.

```
express <project_name>
```

This will create a small example project for you. This example project has a folder named `public`, from which it serves static files. It further contains folders named `javascripts` and `stylesheets`.

The relevant piece of the example project for setting this up is the following line in the file `app.js` in the function passed to `app.configure`.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Example is from express 3.0.0rc1

Express is built on Connect. The docs for it's static middleware might be helpful: [Connect : Static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also in the process i learned that express creates project using JADE as default template engine. If you need ejs use the command "express -e <project-name>"

Comment: If on top of this I also want to serve a separate subfolder (not in public folder)by accessing http://mywebsite.com/subfolder. How do I do it? Thanks!