# How to make the node.js server also send js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, load, client-server

I have a `node.js` file server running which (when visited) returns a html content. Also in the same directory of the `node.js` file, there is a javascript file called `test.js`. Also in the html content being returned, I need to load that javascript file. However in the html content, being returned, which comes out to be called `index.html`, the script looks like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>`

But the server isn't sending the `test.js` file, its only sending the `index.html` file, and the script link is loading it relatively from the same directory.

Now I don't want to give the url to the `test.js` file. I want the `node.js` file to also send the `test.js` file, so that it ends up in the same directory as `index.html`. And then `index.html` can load it from the same directory.

Is there a way I can specify in the `node.js` with code to also send the `test.js` file?

Thanks.

Comment: What about hosting your js file(s) on a web server and specifying the complete URL of the js in the src attribute of the script tag

Comment: Check that link as well:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710995/how-to-include-css-and-js-files-in-node-js-project

Comment: sounds like express or one of the other REST toolkits.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with Express, as dandavis mentioned? Express allows you to set a directory for your static files. See my standard config below:

```
app
  .use('view engine', jade)
  .use(express.compress())
  .use(express.limit('10mb'))
  .use(express.bodyParser())
  .use(app.router)
  .use(stylus.middleware({
     src: __dirname + '/www',
     compile: function(str, path) {
          return stylus(str)
              .set('filename', path)
              .set('compress', false)
              .set('warn', true);
        }
    }))
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'))
  .use(express.logger());
```

The important part here is second from the bottom. Essentially, Express now knows to look for any assets you specify in your HTML within that static directory. For me, I create a folder titled WWW within my server folder, then add to it my JS, CSS, and images.
   For example, say I create the "stylus" folder within my WWW folder, and add to it store.css. My link to that CSS asset would be the following in my Jade template:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="stylus/store.css")
```

Express knows to look for that asset relative to the __dirname + '/www' path, and thus locates the "stylus" folder and the CSS assets it contains. Hope this helps, and that I haven't ventured away from your intent!